# Validating an alphanumeric string having 8 or 11 chars and ending with a specific string

Tags: javascript, regex

What would be regex for alphanumeric length is 8 or 11 and not end with `XXX`.

For example:

Invalid:

```
Ah7AyXXX
ahs221ssXXX
aed3
```

Valid:

```
Xg6tSSw3
ahs221sssws
```

In JavaScript, I tried with

```
(^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}(XXX)$)|(^[a-zA-Z0-9]{11}$)
```

The pattern only matches some valid strings and also matches some invalid strings, you can see it in [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/02PbVC/2):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?!.*XXX$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{3})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/02PbVC/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*XXX$)` - right after, there cannot be any zero or more chars other than line break chars and then `XXX` at the end of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}` - eight alnum chars
- `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{3})?` - optional three alnum chars
- `$` - end of string.